# Empirical power for normality tests

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have this code to calculate empirical power for the Shapiro-wilk test, Anderson-darling test, and Lilliefors test, I want to make sure the code is correct, and I want also to add standard errors in code but I do not know how?

````
alpha <-0.05;  m <-2000#try small m for a trial run
test1 <-test2 <-test3 <- numeric ( m )
sim <- matrix (1 , 3 , 4)
# estimate power

for ( i in 1: 3 ) {
 n<- c(10,20,50)
 for ( j in 1: m) {
   x <- rt (n[[i]], 3)
   test1 [ j ] <-as.integer (ad.test(x) $p.value<=alpha )
   test2 [ j ] <-as.integer ( shapiro.test ( x )$p.value<=alpha )
   test3 [ j ] <-as.integer (lillie.test (x ) $p.value<=alpha )
 }
 print (c(n[[i]] , mean ( test1 ) , mean ( test2 ) , mean ( test3 )))
 sim [i,] <-c(n[[i]], mean ( test1 ) , mean ( test2 ) , mean ( test3 ))
}
detach ( package : energy ) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Below I make small changes to it more cosmetic than anything else and rewrite it as `sapply` and `replicate` loops. I believe that the new code is simpler.

Then, in the end, the results compare equal.

```r
library(nortest)

set.seed(2022)

alpha <- 0.05
m <- 2000 # try small m for a trial run
test1 <- test2 <-test3 <- integer(m)
n <- c(10, 20, 50)
sim <- matrix(1, nrow = length(n), ncol = 4,
              dimnames = list(NULL, c("n", "Anderson-Darling", "Shapiro-Wilk", "Lilliefors")))
# estimate power

for(i in seq_along(n)) {
  for(j in 1:m) {
    x <- rt(n[[i]], 3)
    test1[ j ] <- ad.test(x)$p.value <= alpha
    test2[ j ] <- shapiro.test(x)$p.value <= alpha
    test3[ j ] <- lillie.test(x)$p.value <= alpha
  }
  print(c(n[[i]], mean( test1 ), mean( test2 ), mean( test3 )))
  sim[i, ] <-c(n[[i]], mean( test1 ), mean( test2 ), mean( test3 ))
}
#> [1] 10.0000  0.1835  0.1905  0.1600
#> [1] 20.0000  0.3135  0.3250  0.2360
#> [1] 50.0000  0.5910  0.6330  0.4785


fun_test <- list(ad.test, shapiro.test, lillie.test)

set.seed(2022)
sim2 <- sapply(n, \(k){
  pval <- replicate(m, {
    x <- rt(k, 3)
    sapply(fun_test, \(f) f(x)$p.value)
  })
  rowMeans(pval <= alpha)
})

rownames(sim2) <- c("Anderson-Darling", "Shapiro-Wilk", "Lilliefors")
sim2 <- cbind(n = n, t(sim2))

sim
#>       n Anderson-Darling Shapiro-Wilk Lilliefors
#> [1,] 10           0.1835       0.1905     0.1600
#> [2,] 20           0.3135       0.3250     0.2360
#> [3,] 50           0.5910       0.6330     0.4785
sim2
#>       n Anderson-Darling Shapiro-Wilk Lilliefors
#> [1,] 10           0.1835       0.1905     0.1600
#> [2,] 20           0.3135       0.3250     0.2360
#> [3,] 50           0.5910       0.6330     0.4785
identical(sim, sim2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your code, but when I try to run it I get this error (Error: unexpected input in "sim2 <- sapply(n, \") do you know how can I fix it and do you know how can I add standard errors in this code?

Comment: The new lambda `\(k)` was introduced in R4.1, if your version is older try `function(k)`. And it's time to update R.